# Two sfValidatorDoctrineUnique on the same form?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

I have one symfony form and want to do two unique validation on fields (Fname,Lname) in a postVlidator

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique
                                                     (
                                                        array( 'model' => 'Test',
                                                               'column' => array('fName'),
                                                      , array('invalid' => 'Invalid fName')));

$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique
                                                     (
                                                        array( 'model' => 'Test',
                                                               'column' => array('Lname'),
                                                      , array('invalid' => 'Invalid Lname')));
```

When i do that the second one override the first one .... where is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine them in the same call to `setPostValidator`. For example:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorAnd(array(
  new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('start_date', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::LESS_THAN_EQUAL, 'end_date'),
  new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password_again'),
)));
```

It's in [the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation#chapter_02_file_upload) (scroll a bit to the top to see the example).